# Infinitely many independent experiments. What is the probability of seeing $x$ ($x≥1$) consecutive successes infinitely often?

Tags: probability

One performs infinitely many independent experiments. The nth experiment is successful with probability $n^{−α}$ and fails with probability $1−n^{−α}$ , where $α>0$. Let $x≥1$.  What is the probability of seeing $x$ consecutive successes infinitely often?

I considered the two cases:

1. $α>1$
2. $0<α≤1$

In the first case, the probability is $0$.

In the second case, I attempted to use what I knew about Bernoulli trials but was unsure how to start. I think the Borel-Cantelli Lemmas should also be considered.

Comment: The probability must always be either $0$ or $1$, due to the [zero-one law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero%E2%80%93one_law).

Comment: If $\alpha x>1$, then the expected number of times one observes $x$ consecutive successes is finite hence the probability of observing infinitely many of them is $0$. If $\alpha x\leqslant1$, then, by Borel-Cantelli, one observes $x$ consecutive successes between times $kx+1$ and $(k+1)x$ for infinitely many $k$s, almost surely. A fortiori, one observes $x$ consecutive successes infinitely many times, almost surely.

Comment: @Did: That looks like an answer.

Comment: If $A_k := \{k $ consecutive successes occur$\}$, how would you show that the sequence $\sum_n P(A_n) < \infty$ in the first case and $\sum_n P(A_n) = \infty$ in the second? I'm thinking that $P(A_k) = n^{\alpha} \cdots (n+k)^{\alpha} = 1/k!^{\alpha}$? From which the 0/1 result follows with Borel-Cantelli.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Provided one expands it and one justifies every step, indeed this is a good basis for an answer.

Comment: @KateSinclair Sorry but what are you talking about? To begin with, why introduce these events $A_k$? And why do their probabilities suddenly depend on $n$?

Comment: Sure, which step is not crystal clear? Please be specific.

Comment: @Did $k$ is meant to be $x$ and the dependence on $n$ is from the probabilities of success $n^{-\alpha}$. Thanks

Comment: @KateSinclair Sorry but this explains nothing, in particular not how the probability that $x$ consecutive successes occur can depend on $n$.

Comment: @Did How can you argue that "if $αx>1$, then the expected number of times one observes x consecutive successes is finite" and the opposite for $αx⩽1$ ?

Comment: @rtyjkl3 ?? Is this your conception of "being specific"? We are far from the count...

Comment: @Did I just don't understand the step between $αx>1$ and your conclusion of the expectation. Sorry I can't be more specific - I don't understand the jump between the two

Comment: The "jump" is that if the expected number of times when something happens is finite then the number of times itself is almost surely finite. // But tell me, how do you know that "In the first case, the probability is 0"?

Comment: @Did I wasn't sure if it was 0, I was talking with a friend about it and he said due to the probability of success being $n^{−α}$ it would be 0 for $α>1$ ||   I understand what we can conclude from the finite expectation, I just don't understand how we can say the expectation is in fact finite

Comment: Hi @Did, I am also confused on the same part - how does $\alpha x >1 $ tell us that the expectation is finite? Thanks

Comment: @KateSinclair The probability $p_x(n)$ that every result between the $n$-th and the $n+x-1$-th is a success is $p_x(n)=$ $____$, and $p_x(n)\sim n^{-\beta}$ with $\beta=$ $____$, hence the total number of times $N_x$ when this happens has expectation $E(N_x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty p_x(n)$, which, if $\alpha x>1$, is finite hence $N_x$ is finite almost surely.