# Long run probability of consecutive successes with time-dependent success probability

Tags: probability

We perform infinitely many independent trials. The $n$th trial is a success with probability $p(n)$ (i.e. probability is dependent on $n$) and fails with probability $1-p(n)$.

Let $a≥1$. What is the probability of seeing $a$ consecutive successes?

Comment: In how many trials?

Comment: The [Borel-Cantelli Lemmas](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-BC.pdf) are helpful here.  See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205106/infinitely-many-independent-experiments-what-is-the-probability-of-seeing-x)

Comment: It would likely depend on $p(n)$. Do you have a condition on $p(n)$, such as having a lower bound? If $\lim_{n\to\infty} p(n)=0$ if could be touchy.

Comment: This seems like a difficult problem in general. But if $\liminf_{n \to \infty} p(n) > 0$, then the probability is 1.

Answer (score 1):

It does depend on $p$. For the simple case where $a=1$, the probability of ever seeing a success is
$$
1-\prod_1^\infty (1-p(k))
$$
which can be anywhere between $0$ and $1$ depending on the choice of $p$.